# console.log() outputs an other value than it should

Tags: javascript

When I code practice in codewar.com, I meet a difficulty. Without (in)correct return. But `console.log()` outputs the correct value. Can you help me?

```js
function findN(m,n = 1,v = 0){
    if(m == 1){
        return n;
    }else if(v < m){
        v += n * n * n;
        n++;
        let newN = n - 1;
        if(v == m){
            console.log(newN);
            return newN;
        }
        newN = null;
        findN(m,n,v);

    }else if(v > m){
        return -1;
    }
}
findN(4183059834009);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Maby i describe this quetion not good.This is codewar website [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/build-a-pile-of-cubes/train/javascript) 
In this website i already run this code,but i can't have correct answer.I can't pass test.

Comment: So the problem is with the logic inside your function and not with how you use the result? In this case you have to specify precisely in the question which result you expect, what the function should do and where your function fails to do that.

Comment: when this code run in my browers  i can't have correct answer.(return value) But this value is correct.(newN).Thank you answer.QAQI'm very grateful to you.

Comment: Logic is correct.

Comment: You method `findN` is not compatible with the codewar link you linked to. They expect a function `findNb`.

Answer (score 3):

A return value is only used if you store the result in a variable or use it somewhere else in the calling method. Otherwise the result is going nowhere.

You can, for example, write something like

```
var foo = findN(4183059834009);
```

to store the return result in a variable called `foo`.

Another option would be to directly use the returned result in a statement similar to

```
console.log(findN(1222655))
```

Comment: it was not about exiting it's about returning a value @desoares

Comment: @desoares I fixed the answer, please retract the downvotes

Comment: @Marie: I edited your answer. If you don't like the changes, feel free to roll it back in the edit menu. My initial point was that `is only used if you store it....` might be misleading since it isn't necessary to store the result in a variable in order to use it.

Comment: First ,this is my first in the website request answer.I'm very grateful.This is codewar Title Description。

Comment: Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 1^3.

You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.

Comment: Is there a return value that may run on your browser? Would you like to try it?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is, that you are calling the function recursively, but don't pass the result of the subfunction calls back. Currently the `findN` method has three different cases:

- return n: fine
- return -1: fine
- call `findN(m,n,v);` **and return nothing** This happens since you don't return anything in this case and javascript automatically returns `undefined`.

If you want to pass the result from function calls back, you have to explicitly return it like this:

```
return findN(m,n,v);
```

The full code sample should be:

```
function findN(m,n = 1,v = 0){
    if(m == 1){
        return n;
    }else if(v < m){
        v += n * n * n;
        n++;
        let newN = n - 1;
        if(v == m){
            console.log(newN);
            return newN;
        }
        newN = null;
        return findN(m,n,v);

    }else if(v > m){
        return -1;
    }
}
```